# Gradle subproject not recognizing 3rd party dependencies from root build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project like this:

- module1

  - src/
  - build.gradle
- module2

  - src/
  - build.gradle
- build.gradle
- settings.gradle

In the root build.gralde I am defining 3rd party dependencies needed by all submodules. However, in intellij the submodules don't seem to recognize the dependencies and won't compile. I've seen this work in the past and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Root build.gradle
    plugins {
        id 'java'
    }

```
group 'com.XXX'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies { 
   ...
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'XXX'
include 'module1'
include 'module2'
```

module1 build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.XXX'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized I just needed to put the dependencies in the root build.gradle within a "subprojects" block and add the java plugin as well.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This or the `allProjects` clojure could be used to share dependencies across modules. Same goes for plugins. If you have the same plugins for the various submodules you might as well define them within the `allProjects` clojure.